# Trying to cp a path with spaces, fails when scripted but echoing and pasting succeeds?

Tags: bash, osx, cp

I have a script that is trying to copy a directory from a path that includes backslash-escaped spaces and is stored in a string variable to a subdirectory of the working directory.

When I run the script, I get the usage for `cp`:

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

However, if I echo the command, it looks perfectly correct. And even if I then copy and paste that echoed line back into the terminal, it executes fine!

```
rm -rf Payload
mkdir Payload
echo cp -Rf $APP_PROTOTYPE/ Payload/${BUNDLE_NAME}.app
cp -Rf $APP_PROTOTYPE/ Payload/${BUNDLE_NAME}.app
```

I'm at a loss to understand why it would not execute properly in Bash, but manually pasting the command back in works flawlessly. Moreover I can't even tell what the problem is because it works fine when I do it manually (however I obviously suspect the spaces). The exit code from `cp` is 64, if that helps at all.

`$APP_PROTOTYPE` looks like `.golden_repo/Production\ Releases\ Only/Kiosk/1.0.3/Prototype/Kiosk.app`, and note that `.golden_repo` is a mounted smbfs share.

Comment: Are you attempting to copy a directory to a file?

Comment: @slm That's my guess, too. I think the problem is that `${BUNDLE_NAME}.app` already exists and is a regular file, which is why the copy fails. chaiguy, can you check whether `Payload/${BUNDLE_NAME}.app` already exists?

Comment: It doesn't exist. The `Payload` directory is empty (as you can see I delete it and recreate it before the copy). Also the .app is actually a directory (it's an iOS app bundle).

Comment: first off - you're using slash (/) instead of backslash (\) for escaping spaces in the paths. I believe that would solve your problem. Next - the question should be improved.

Comment: @user176181 It actually just looks like that, but those are really two arguments, the first of which ends in a forward slash.

Comment: On Apple file-systems there is a concept of "Bundle" (a.k.a "Package") which is a Directory, that LOOKS LIKE a file to the user. the .app is NOT a file, but rather a directory, whose "bundle" bit (extended attribute) is turned on. That should have worked fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to quote parts of your command containing spaces to prevent word splitting from making them into two different arguments:

```
cp -Rf "$APP_PROTOTYPE/" "Payload/${BUNDLE_NAME}.app"
```

should do what you want. Note that you need double quotes rather than single quotes to allow for variable interpolation inside the quotes.

The output of `echo` doesn't mean that the command should work properly. Unlike `cp`, which deals in path names, `echo` is perfectly fine with one argument becoming several ones due to word splitting:

```
echo 'a b'
```

and

```
echo a b
```

should both produce the same result.

Comment: Unfortunately it has no effect. I tried escaping the quotes as well but no difference. I still get the usage comment.

Comment: @chaiguy Answer updated. I wasn't paying attention. I thought that " Payload/" was the part of the path with spaces and failed to notice that it's the destination of the copy.

Comment: Is he copying a directory to a file?

Comment: Ok getting closer. Now it's complaining "No such file or directory" about the source. It's certainly there though. @slm I'm trying to recursively copy a directory into another directory.

Comment: @chaiguy Are you sure the Samba share is working properly?

Comment: Yes. Like I said I can literally copy and paste the echoed line and it copies it flawlessly. It's as though the command is being interpreted differently from within the script than it is when I type the exact same thing on the command line.

Comment: Here's what I'm getting now: `cp: .golden_repo/Production\ Releases\ Only/Kiosk/1.0.3/Prototype/Kiosk.app: No such file or directory`

Comment: @chaiguy Yes, that's because you don't need the backslash anymore when you quote your strings. In quoted strings, this file name is interpreted as containing a literal backslash followed by a space.