# The output I get via "echo" works as a command when pasted to terminal, but not in the script

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames

I'm trying to change the files generated by an app that unfortunately often contain spaces. I have managed to get "echo" to give me output that works if copy pasted into terminal, but when I try to do the command, it does not work. I looked at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98238/trying-to-cp-a-path-with-spaces-fails-when-scripted-but-echoing-and-pasting-suc) answer, which has helped me before, but even the "${x}" syntax does not seem to work in this case.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/Data
IFS=$'\n';for i in $(ls); do
    echo "$i";
    filename="$i"
    date=$(date -n +%Y-%m-%d)
    new_filename="$date$filename"
    echo mv \'"${filename}"\' \'"${new_filename}"\'
    mv \'"${filename}"\' \'"${new_filename}"\'
done;
```

Comment: For the record you also had extra quotes on the mv line.

Comment: What do you mean? The echo mv and mv lines are identical, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that you loop over output of `ls` command. Use glob `*` instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/Data
for i in *; do
    echo "$i"
    filename="$i"
    date=$(date -n +%Y-%m-%d)
    new_filename="${date}${filename}"
    echo mv "${filename}" "${new_filename}"
    mv -- "${filename}" "${new_filename}"
done
```

Additionally I added `--` to `mv` in order to treat correctly files which names begin with `-`. And btw my `date` command doesn't have `-n` option, but I leave it as you may have different version.

Answer (score 1):

The other problem you had was that you also had extra quotes on the mv line. When you are using echo to print a command that will be copied to a shell you need quote everything twice, once for this shell, and once for the second. your echo mv worked fine as long as the filename did not begin with a dash or contain a single quote. The mv only needed quoted once.

Here is how I would rewrite your snippet.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Data
date="$(date -n +%Y-%m-%d)"

for filename in *; do
    echo "${filename}"
    new_filename="$date$filename"
    filename_e="$(echo "$filename"|sed -e 's!\('\''\)!\\\1!')"
    new_filename_e="$(echo "$new_filename"|sed -e 's!\('\''\)!\\\1!')"
    echo mv -- \'"${filename_e}"\' \'"${new_filename_e}"\'
    mv -- "${filename}" "${new_filename}"
done;
```

This version will correctly rename any file with any character in the name. the only limitation is that the echoed command may produce commands that do not work in files that have a newline in the name.

Comment: thanks, the added functionality of working with filenames containing any character is very cool!

Answer (score -1):

You just need to treat filename adding an escape caracter `\` before the space.

```
filename=$(echo $i|sed 's/ /\\ /g')
mv $filename $new_filename
```

Comment: Please test your answers before posting. This will make no difference whatsoever. The problem is that `$i` does not contain the entire file name, each word of the name will be saved as a separate `$i`. You are also not quoting your variables which can cause all sorts of problems. Finally, you should also consider that not all whitespace consists of spaces. You can also have tabs, newlines etc in a filename.

Comment: They have been tested, test your comments before posting them. As you can see his code has IFS=$'\n' which makes $i get the righ name for every file SPACES INCLUDED. So the answer is perfectly right and I have tested before posting. No need to quote variables since spaces have been escaped before. Be sure when you make a comment correcting something you are right before you place the comment.

Comment: Well, the _question_ had `IFS=$'\n'`, your answer did not, so I didn't realize. Still, you're right, my comment was more aggressive than was necessary, sorry. Nevertheless, this will still break if the whitespace is not a simple space and your `sed` will only escape the first space.

Comment: You're right about multi spaces, I have added the ending 'g' to substitute all of them in case there are more than one.

Comment: Thanks, but this still breaks on tabs, newlines, carriage returns, file names beginning with `-` etc. It is also needlessly complicated and creates problems where there were none by [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The Right Way© is to either use shell globbing or `find -print0` instead.

Comment: You're right, none of those characters are being escaped, but the question states nothing about that and the answer solves the question problem. There are better answers and there may be more complete and excellent solutions, but the answer was for trying to solve the OP problem and that specific problem was solved with this answer. If you want to post the perfect solution we all sure be glad to have it and many people will benefit from it, so even if the answer has been marked as solved please do post it.

Comment: It already has been posted, see Jimmyj's solution above. In any case, note that I retracted my downvote after your first comment since you were right that in this particular case, since the OP was using the (cumbersome but sufficient) `IFS=$'\n'`.